# mongodb difference remove() vs findOneAndDelete() vs deleteOne()

Tags: mongodb, express

In express and mongodb I want delete document by id
findOneAndDelete() Can not delete by _id, can only delete by field ! why ?

```
db.collection('quotes').findOneAndDelete({name: req.body.name}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
  })

var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
  var collection = db.collection('quotes');
  collection.remove({_id: new ObjectId(req.body.id)}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          res.send('A darth vadar quote got deleted')
      }
  });

  var mongodb = require('mongodb');
  db.collection('quotes', function(err, collection) {
    collection.deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectID(req.body.id)});
  });
```

Difference of three functions?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In short:

- [`findOneAndDelete()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#findOneAndDelete) returns the deleted document after having deleted it (in case you need its contents after the delete operation);
- [`deleteOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#deleteOne) is used to delete a single document
- [`remove()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#remove) is a deprecated function and has been replaced by `deleteOne()` (to delete a single document) and `deleteMany()` (to delete multiple documents)

`findOneAndDelete()` should be able to delete on `_id`.

Comment: very clean answer, which one is recommend to use in case of only delete operation

Comment: @HidaytRahman `deleteOne` (for a single document) or `deleteMany` (for multiple documents)

Comment: @robertkelp  Thank you, It means we should not use ``findOneAndDelete()``

Comment: Its upto you, if you need record after deleting, use findOneAndDelete().

Comment: Thanks for this short and crisp answer.